# Webapp can't write to /tmp directory with Ubuntu 20.04 and Tomcat 9

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I'm migrating a Tomcat web application from an old version of Ubuntu and Tomcat 7 to Ubuntu 20.04 and Tomcat 9.  The app writes various files to the /tmp directory, but after switching to Ubuntu 20.04 and Tomcat 9 writing to the /tmp directory silently fails.  I don't see anything in the Tomcat logs indicating why the files aren't getting written, nor is my application throwing an exception (I would expect to get an IO exception or something if the app couldn't write to the directory).

I did a little experimenting, and I was able to write files to /var/lib/tomcat/logs.  Is there a configuration parameter that I need to change either in Tomcat or Ubuntu to allow Tomcat to write to /tmp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On recent Debianoids (since Debian Buster) the `tomcat9.service` runs in its own **mnt namespace** (cf. [Linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces)). The only mount point, which is different from the *"real"* filesystem is `/tmp` and it is located under:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-*-tomcat9.service-*/tmp
```

and it is unreachable to normal users (its parent is chmod `700` and owned by `root`).

If you wish Tomcat to share the `/tmp` directory with the rest of the system, you can override the `tomcat9.service` file through:

```sh
systemctl edit tomcat9.service
```

and add:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=no
```

(cf. [SystemD documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=)).

**Edit:** as you remarked in a comment the `tomcat9.service` has [`ProtectSystem=strict`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectSystem=) set, so the service sees all filesystems read-only. Therefore you either need:

```
ProtectSystem=off
```

or

```
ReadWritePaths=/tmp
```

Comment: After updating the tomcat service config, I get IO exceptions when I try to write to the /tmp directory.  The error says "read only file system", but it's not.  Other processes can write to /tmp.  Is there something else I need to do to allow Tomcat to write to /tmp.

Comment: Looks like I also need to include ReadWritePaths=/tmp when updating the tomcat9 service config.  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by editing the file under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`

and editing from

```
PrivateTmp=True
```

to

```
PrivateTmp=no
```